# position horizontal scrollbar at bottom of window

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, scrollview, scrollbar

I am currently working on a Flutter app, and I have the screen divided into two regions. The left region takes up about 1/3 of the screen width, while the right region takes up the other 2/3 of the width. Here is a depiction:

[image: basic depiction of screen area of app]

In section "A", I have a custom "tree view" widget that is based on a DataTable. It allows the user to expand/collapse parts of the tree. The tree view is also scrollable in both the horizontal and vertical directions, just in case it consumes more screen real estate than is available in region A.

Currently, if the tree view doesn't consume the entire height of region A, then the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the tree view simply appears at the bottom of the tree view, as depicted in the following image:

[image: depiction of current scrollbar placement]

However, this is not where I want the horizontal scroll bar to be placed. I want it at the bottom of the window, regardless of the size of the tree view widget, as depicted in the following image:

[image: depiction of desired scrollbar placement]

The code for my widget tree is as follows:

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) 
    {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            body: 
                Row(
                    children: [
                        Expanded(flex: 1, 
                            child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                child: Container(
                                    height: double.infinity,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    child: Scrollbar(
                                        scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
                                        isAlwaysShown: false,
                                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                            child: Scrollbar(
                                                isAlwaysShown: false,
                                                scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.bottom,
                                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                    child: TreeViewWidget(
                                                        model: model, 
                                                        dataheader_color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 230, 230),
                                                        tree_expander_style: TreeExpanderStyle.PlusMinusOutlined,
                                                        show_header_row: true
                                                    ),
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        Expanded(flex: 2, 
                            child: Column(
                                children: const [

                                ],
                            )
                        )
                    ]
                )
        );
    }
```

How can I get the horizontal scroll bar to correctly place itself at the bottom of the window, rather than immediately below the tree view widget?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support both horizontal and vertical scrollbars, it's probably easiest to use a library, for example [cross_scroll](https://pub.dev/packages/cross_scroll) or [adaptive_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_scrollbar#multiple-scrollbars), to name a few. I recommend you check out those packages or find other packages, instead of writing your own.

If you really want to do it yourself, you can try to lift up the `Scrollbar` to be outside of your `Container`, but make sure you use a `ScrollController` to connect them. For example (modified from the code in your question):

[image: demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('demo')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Scrollbar( // <-- move the scroll bar here
                controller: _controller, // <-- controller
                isAlwaysShown: true,
                scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.bottom,
                child: Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: _controller, // <-- controller
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Scrollbar(
                      isAlwaysShown: true,
                      scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.right,
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          width: 1000,
                          height: 300,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: FlutterLogo(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```